# Set hint of textinputlayout ALWAYS above edittext?

Tags: java, android

How do I set the `hint` of `TextInputlayout` to be ALWAYS above `EditText`? That means I don't have to click the `EditText` to make it slide up. Right now, the hint of `EditText` and the hint of `TextInputLayout` are overlapping, I want them to be separated!

My current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:hint="My Hint Text"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            app:hintAnimationEnabled="false">

            <EditText
                android:hint="Type here"
                android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I will immediately accept the working answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main functionality of the InputText Layout is floating edittext, password toggling and error visible.

So if you want hint above edittext then please take one textview and set edittext below it.

**Don't use TextInput layout if you don't want the exact behaviour provided by it.**

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to have the hint always on top too. Must say @Chirag has an important point, but I wanted an easy way for the `endIcon` functionality.

So very simple workaround: **set a blank into the `TextInputEditText` e.g.**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text" >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" " />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

When processing the input I make sure if the blank was deleted.

Comment: This is smart ! great

Answer (score 0):

things have moved on since these answers, there's a simple property that will do exactly this.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       // your other properties
       app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
       // etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

this will solve your problem

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/relativeID"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="My Hint Text"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:hint="Type here"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                   />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```